# What is wrong with this quicksort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```java
public class QuicksortRandomPivot{
    
    Random rand = new Random();

    private int partitioning(int [] array,  int first, int last){
        int randPivot = rand.nextInt(last - first) + first;
        int pivot = array[randPivot];
        int i = first - 1;
        swap(array, randPivot, last);
    
        for (int j = first; j <= last - 1; j++){
            if (array[j]<= pivot){
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
        swap(array, i+1, last);
        return i+1;
    }

    private void quickSorting(int [] array, int first, int last){
        if (first  < last){
            int pivot = partitioning(array, first, last);
            quickSorting(array, first, last - 1);
            quickSorting(array, first + 1, last);
        }
    
    }
```

BTW there is more to the code but it is just swap and sort method which I'm pretty sure work perfectly so the problem definitely lies somewhere here. Why is my code so slow? Whenever I try with an array length more than 30 it takes kinda a lot of time, specially if I try with 50 or over then it runs but nothing gets printed out so there has got to be a problem. This was my understanding of how the implementation should go, am I correct? If not what did I do wrong?

Comment: In the `quickSorting` method, you have an unused variable called `pivot`.

Comment: You are supposed to subsort from first to pivot and pivot+1 to last, but you are sorting almost all of the elements in both subsorts,

Comment: Adding Random isn't an issue? See: https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort

Comment: Looking at a few sites (inc Baeldung and Wikipedia), I don’t see that they have that extra `swap` before the `for`.

Comment: Still not getting why `int randPivot = rand.nextInt(last - first) + first;` is making this **any** better.

Comment: @BillMair There's nothing inherently wrong with using a random pivot, it's a reasonable and not highly uncommon pivot selection strategy. It's easy to implement, it's fast to calculate, and it has a very low probability of resulting in quadratic runtime, and there's no specific common types of input on which it is guaranteed to cause quadratic runtime. Yes, unlike median-of-medians pivot selection that guarantees a worst-case `O(nlogn)` run-time, it _could_ still result in an unlucky `O(n^2)` run-time, but that's highly unlikely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should modify your `quickSorting` method and partition the array around the `pivot`.

```
private void quickSorting(int [] array, int first, int last){
    if (first  < last){
        int pivot = partitioning(array, first, last);
        quickSorting(array, first, pivot - 1);
        quickSorting(array, pivot + 1, last);
    }
}
```