# Why is my quicksort and insertion sort hybrid algorithm not working properly?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, insert, quicksort

```java
public class QuicksortFixedPivotInsertion implements IntSorter{
    InsertionSort insert = new InsertionSort();

    public int partition(int [] array, int first, int last){
        int middle = (first+last)/2;   
        swap(array, middle, last);        
        int pivot = array[last];
        int i = first-1;

        for (int j = first; j < last; j++){
            if (array[j]<pivot){
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);               
    
            }
        } 
        swap(array, i+1, last);
        return i+1;
    }

    private void quickSort(int [] array, int first, int last){
     if(first < last){
        if ((last - first) < 10){
            insert.insertionSort(array, first, last);
        }
        else {
            int pivot = partition(array, first, last);
            quickSort(array, first, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(array, pivot + 1, last);
        }
     }
    }

    public void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
           int temp = arr[i];
           arr[i] = arr[j];
           arr[j] = temp;
       }

  
    public void sort(int [] v){
        quickSort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the insertion method that is used for this

```java
public class InsertionSort {

    public void insertionSort(int [] arr, int first, int last){
        for(int i = first + 1; i<last ; i++){
            int temp;
            int j = i;
            while(j > first && arr[j-1] > arr[j]){
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = temp;
                j--;

            }
        } 
    }

    public void sort(int[] v){
        insertionSort(v, 0, v.length);

    }
```

> So the problem is that it doesn't work properly, as in when I try it
> with array with different sizes and different types of data (sorted
> array, shuffled array, random) it doesn't always work. By  it doesn't
> work, I mean that it doesn't sort the array correctly.  For example it
> doesn't sort shuffled or random arrays. Here is an example:

int[] a ={1,13,53,3,646,75,4,4646,332,2,124,3563,242,234,35,2,1};

> This is the sorted version that gets printed:

[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 13, 35, 75, 124, 234, 242, 53, 332, 3563, 4646, 646]

> Can someone help me solve this issue. I have checked that my
> insertion method and quicksort algorithm (partition method) works
> perfectly fine so the issue has to be somewhere in the quicksort
> method. Btw I have seen some similar posts on stack overflow and none
> of them worked in my case. One of the tips I tried there worked better
> but it was not consistent. As in when it comes to even & odd arrays,
> sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't when using random data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain your problem *without* using "doesn't work".

Comment: I see you have used the answer from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762911/what-is-wrong-with-this-quicksort-algorithm), but you have not awarded that answer with an acceptance mark. Why?

Comment: @trincot that was a different question, that was for implementing a quicksort just itself. As I said in the question, insertion and quicksort by themselves work. Anyways, I am new to stack overflow, what does awarding mean? Was there something I should have done? Or am I not allowed to post about similar subjects twice even tho I need help with different things?

Comment: @Sören thanks for tips. I hope it is clear now!

Comment: So no exceptions, just the wrong result? Could you also please add *one* example input that is sorted wrong?

Comment: Okay so I've added an example now. Yeah no exceptions. I obviously get a stack overflow error when using large arrays (even tho my algorithm should not until a data size of 1m  according to my requirement but that is another problem)

Comment: @User, I know it was a different question. It was about an error in your Quicksort, and the only answer there gives a correction of that error, and you have used that correction in the code that you presented in this question, so I feel you should award that guy's answer to your previous question. Mark that answer with the checkmark that is next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's a classic: Off-by-one error. Let's have a look at your two sorter classes:

```java
public class QuicksortFixedPivotInsertion implements IntSorter{
    /* ... */
    private void quickSort(int [] array, int first, int last){
        /* ... */
    }
  
    public void sort(int [] v){
        quickSort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
    }
}
```

```java
public class InsertionSort {

    public void insertionSort(int [] arr, int first, int last){
        /* ... */
    }

    public void sort(int[] v){
        insertionSort(v, 0, v.length);
    }
}
```

See the difference? That `-1`? That's not where the error is, but that is giving us a hint, at what is wrong here: Your `last` parameter means two different things! In the QuickSort case, it's the index of the last element to sort, in the InsertionSort case, it's *one past* the last element to sort.

And now look what happens when QuickSort calls InsertionSort:

```java
            insert.insertionSort(array, first, last);
```

You need to translate from one convention to the other, so that last parameter needs to be `last+1`.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, it works now. Thanks for the help! But do you have any idea why it is causing stack overflow error when the data is equal and the size is 10k. The things is that quicksort algorithm alone doesn't cause a stack overflow error at array length 10k and when the data is equal. So why does this hybrid algorithm cause that type of error. In addition could I make some changes in the partition to avoid stack overflow until data size is 1 million for equal data?

Comment: That sounds like a great next question!